# Get logged in user's calendarId

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to retrieve calendar events of the logged in user. The API doc [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) suggests that I need to pass 'primary' as calendarId for the logged in user.

Therefore the URL becomes `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/`

I am getting a 401 on this URL.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/ 401 ()
```

Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass a different calendarId (email address of a calendar). To get your calendarID, you can follow the steps specified [here](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/find-google-calendar-id/).

And to know about the error you encountered, here is the document about [401: Invalid Credentials](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials).

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization",
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Suggested actions:

> - Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.
> - If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described    in [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).
> - If you are seeing this for a service account, check that you have    successfully completed all the steps in the [service account
>
>     page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).